# Regex not contain at end and start differents string

Tags: php, regex, laravel, eloquent

i want to take only mail address which not contains 'xxx-' at the start and '@test.com' at the end of the mail string.

Here my code :

```
->where('email', 'regexp', "/^((?!@test.com).)*$/i")
```

Here i take only email where not  contains 'test.com' at the end.
I want to not take email where the start is 'xxx-' too. Anyone know how to do this ?
Thank you !

Comment: Can you just clarify/confirm whether you do in fact mean "not contains 'xxx-' at the start _and_ '@test.com' at the end" or if you mean "not contains 'xxx-' at the start _or_ '@test.com' at the end"?

Comment: Use `^(?!xxx-)(?!.*@test\.com$).*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with 2 negative lookahead assertions (rules):

```
^(?!xxx-)(?![^@]+@test\.com$)[^@]+@[^@]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3mET7i/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!xxx-)`: Don't allow email to start with `xxx-`
- `(?![^@]+@test\.com$)`: Don't allow email to end with `test.com`
- `[^@]+@[^@]+`: Match an email that must have only one `@`
- `$`: End

Comment: Looks like it's not matching the first example there, you'll want to accept any characters between those two lookahead assertions: 
`^(?!xxx-).+(?!@test\.com$)`
https://regex101.com/r/3mET7i/2

Comment: It is matching first one already. See `1 match` in green in my demo. It is not highlighted because of zero width. Change it to `^(?!xxx-)(?!@test\.com$).+`